# Plotting a function as a single line with different values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a way to plot a function as a single line of color (in 1D), where the color is defined based on value of the function.

i.e. y=sin(x) will be plotted like a single line with changing gradient.

Comment: If you could post a picture showing what you mean it might be a bit more clear

Comment: How do you map sin(x) onto the colourspace? eg  for RGB you have a scalar mapping onto 3 values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500700/how-to-plot-a-gradient-color-line-in-matplotlib

Comment: And the ever useful Joe Kington http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13622909/matplotlib-how-to-colorize-a-large-number-of-line-segments-as-independent-gradi/13649811#13649811

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multicolored_line.html

Comment: Why does this question receive so many up-votes? I am genuinely interested.