# How to plot a matplotlib line plot using colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, line-plot

How can I create a lineplot using python matplotlib in such a way that the color of the line varies in respect of another series?

For a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
z = (t-1) ** 2

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(t, y)
ax.plot(t, z)
plt.show()
```

Instead of:

[image: lineplots]

I would like to graph only (t, y) in a way that the line color represents the value of z following a certain colormap (cmap), for instance 'plasma'.

Edit:

This question was tagged as possibly duplicate, but references to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8500700/how-to-plot-a-gradient-color-line-in-matplotlib) where the desired result is a line changing color to help follow the path it was draw (sequence information), instead of adding information on another value (in this case z).

It is closer to [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html), as pointed out in the comments, but I was looking for something simpler than having to create a set of line segments and color them individually.

Comment: Seems like the [multicolored_line example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html) isn't very traceable. Can you help us and tell which notions you used in your search engine that would not result in this popping up?

Comment: Thank you for the interest, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest. I could reach the multicolored_line example before, but _"Create a set of line segments so that we can color them individually. This creates the points as a N x 1 x 2 array so that we can stack points together easily to get the segments. The segments array for line collection needs to be (numlines) x (points per line) x 2 (for x and y)"_ seemed like a hack. I thought there might exist a somewhat simple and direct way...

Comment: I see. Well next time asking a question here, mention such things you found. It'll help you get better answers. So do you have a suggestion how to formulate this differently? There is of course the idea around to have a wrapping function that creates such line collection, but noone has every really worked on it yet.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47851492/plot-curve-with-blending-line-colors-with-matplotlib-pyplot) may be of interest, in case you do not want to see the individual segments in the plot. Appart, I don't know what "simpler" would mean. If you have a clear vision of what you expect, you can of course describe it as detailed as possible and we can reopen the question?

Comment: Conceptually there aren’t options other than coloring by line segment i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252412/ but you could write a function that interpolated to smooth the color transitions out of that as your concern.  See also the last comment in that answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252412/ may indeed be a better duplicate (as it uses `t` as independent variable), but I'm still a bit lost on what the desired answer here is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`colorline`](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/dpsanders/matplotlib-examples/blob/master/colorline.ipynb) function referenced [in an answer to the question you said is not a duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25941474/4042267), this can be done:

```
from colorline import colorline

colorline(t, y, z)
plt.xlim(t.min(), t.max())
plt.ylim(y.min(), y.max())
plt.show()
```

[image]

This creates multiple line segments, each with a color determined by `z`.

Comment: See that's the problem of the question being reopened. You get the same duplicate answers. :-(

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: But in which sense does this part not answer the question as asked? It *is* a slightly different answer than to the other question (for which the OP of the other answer had to adopt this function, whereas it was directly intended to solve a problem like this).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to do it with line plots, but with scatter, it's pretty easy. If you still want a connecting line, you can fake it a bit with a gray line behind it:

```
ax.scatter(t, y, c=z, marker='.')
ax.plot(t, y, c='gray')
```

[image: enter code here]